# \edtextlater (reledmac, reledpar) issues an error

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I want my critical notes called on the left side and printed on the right side. This is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage[series={A},nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\setstanzaindents{12,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\lineation{pstart}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
[\section*{Latin section title}]
\pend

\begin{astanza}
Versus 1&
Versus 2&
Versus 3&
Versus 4&
\edtextlater{Versus 5}{\Afootnote{Comment on line 5.}}&
Versus 6\&
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
[\section*{Translated section title}]
\pend

\pstart
Prose translation.
\edtextnow
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages  

\end{document}
```

I get this error:
    Cfootnote outside of the second argument of an edtext

With normal \edtext I have no problem.

Any help?
Thanx!

Comment: I get no error in a current miktex or texlive. (But I don't know if I get the wanted output.)

Comment: I get no error too, except a spurious space that will be corrected quickly. After three run, I also get the expected ouput. Which version of reledmac/reledpar do you use?

Comment: U use MiKTeX 2.9, and packages are from the version you uploaded here: (https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/545). It seemed to have worked without error last night, but \edtextlater messed up the line numbers of other series of notes (I had 3 series, and only one with \edtextlater). This morning, when I wanted to post a question about line numbers, it started to issue an error.

Comment: hum. You should use the standard version of of reledmac/reledpar distributed by MikTeX, and not a development one get on github.

Comment: Yes, I'll try it later today, when I come home. I used the github version because of some problems with the standard version. I tried the example on another computer, and it worked fine. Maybe I just have to get my versions straight. Thank you.

Comment: normally, github version are not stable. Please always use ctan version (except if you need to test devlopment version). And if you have "some problem with the standard version", explain us.

Comment: ps: I have send on CTAN a v. 2.14.2 of reledpar. You should up your distribution in two days, to get this correct version, which fix spurious space.

Comment: Thank you. It was some time ago, when I was new in using eledmac, and I don't remember what was the exact problem. But the github version solved it at that point. I'll make sure to have the most recent version.

Comment: Maïeul, will you post an answer, so that I can mark it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47772/discussion-between-maieul-and-simon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem with this code on my TeXLive. You have used a not official version of reledmac/reledpar, which was in development. Please use normal official version on CTAN and in TeXLive / MikTeX.

However, there is a bug  on the version 2.14.1 of reledpar, which insert a spurious space. Wait some days to get the neweset version 2.14.2.